# How to find the conditional density of $X$ given an event $A$ has happened?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I need some help with this probrem:

> If $X$ is a random variable with density
>
> $f(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
>              \\ c\frac{1}{x^2} &  , & 1\leq X\leq2 \\
>              \\ 0 &  ,  & \text{otherwise}
> \end{array}\right.$
>
> If $A=X>1.5$, find the conditional density of $X$ knowing that $A$ has occurred.

I tried to solve it by defining a indicator varible:

$$I_A =\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \\ 1 &  , & X>1.5 \\
             \\ 0 &  ,  & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Then I used the formula for conditional continous distribution: 
$$f_{X|I_A}(X|I_A)=\frac{f(X,I_A)}{f(I_a)}$$
I don't know how to find $f(X,I_A)$ since if I'm not mistaken they are not independet so I can't just muliply the marginals. How do I fin the conditional density?

Comment: The conditional density will be equal to $\frac{f(x)}{\Bbb{P}(A)}$ for $x > 1.5$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So it is a conditional density of a continous random variabel given a discrete random variable has occurred?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth How do I find $\Bbb{P}(A)$? Is it just the probability that $X$ is bigger that $1.5$?

Comment: $\Bbb{P}(A)$ is just the probability that $X$ is greater than $1.5$. Integrate the density of $X$ over the appropriate range to find this.

Comment: Okay, I've already donde it, the range I used was from $1$ to $1.5$,is it correct?

Comment: This is not correct. The range of values to integrate over should be $1.5$ to $2$, since we want the probability that $X$ is *greater* than $1.5$.

Comment: Yes, you're rigt, but what I did was $\Bbb{P}(A)=\Bbb{P}(X>1.5)=1-\Bbb{P}(X\leq 1.5)$, thats why I chose that rage, is it still wrong?

Comment: That is also fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have one question, does $\frac{f(x)}{\Bbb{P}(A)}$ come from $f_{X|I_A}(X|I_A)=\frac{f(X,I_A)}{f(I_a)}$?

Answer (score 1):

First we compute $c$:
$$
1=\int_0^1 f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^1 \frac c{x^2}\ \mathsf dx = \frac12 c\implies c=2.
$$

The conditional density is given by
$$
f_{X\mid A}(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\mathbb P(A)}\mathsf 1_A.
$$
We compute
$$
\mathbb P(A) = \int_{\frac32}^2 \frac2{x^2}\ \mathsf dx = \frac13.
$$
Hence,
$$
f_{X\mid A}(x) = \frac2{3x^2}\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac32,2\right)}(x).
$$